# echo multiple fields outside while statement in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if look silly as i am a beginner

I am comparing id's and displaying data .

**Expected output**

> Name1 Name2 Name3

**Code.**

```
$cout = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where parent_id='$update_id' ",$link);
while($cput = mysql_fetch_array($cout)){
  echo $cput['s_name'];   
}
```

But, i want to `echo` outside `while loop`, so i tried the following but it outputs only the last value i.e., Name3

```
$cout = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where parent_id='$update_id' ",$link);
while($cput = mysql_fetch_array($cout)){
  $sname = $cput['s_name'];
}
echo $sname;
```

I can understand that the `loop` will terminate after while loop and hence it won't do the required one . But, i think that there might be a work around . Anyone can help me over here please.

Comment: "*i want to echo outside while loop*", why?

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Do appending using concatenation operator like as `$sname .= $cput['s_name'];`

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @D4V1D i am using the ['s_name'] at several places .so i thought instead of using the loop again and again i can try a work around mate .

Comment: @Uchiha That worked , thanks a lot mate

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad it worked for you. But please take @JayBlanchard comment seriously.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sure mate , i will take your comments seriously and will act upon in the future . i am a beginner . just learning things and learning from errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a variable to keep names with space separated ($sname) then concatenate s_name value in each iteration like $sname .= $cput['s_name'] . ' ';

So your code will be like...

```
$cout = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where parent_id='$update_id' ",$link);
$sname = '';
while($cput = mysql_fetch_array($cout)){
    $sname .= $cput['s_name'] . ' ';
}
echo $sname;
```

Answer (score 3):

While using a concatenated variable *works*, note the trailing *space* that will ultimately be outputted. Or imagine you wanted to separate the names with commas. The aforementioned code - with commas - would output:

```
$cout = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where parent_id='$update_id' ",$link);
$sname = '';
while($cput = mysql_fetch_array($cout)){
    $sname .= $cput['s_name'] . ', ';
}
echo $sname; // Name1, Name2, Name3, // note trailing (unwanted) comma with *space*
```

An alternative to this would be to capture the output in an array. This would allow you to then [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) whatever delimiter you so please. Consider the following:

```
$cout = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where parent_id='$update_id' ",$link);
$sname = [];
while($cput = mysql_fetch_array($cout)){
    $sname[] = $cput['s_name'];
}
echo implode(' ', $sname); // Name1 Name2 Name3
echo implode(', ', $sname); // Name1, Name2, Name3
echo implode('<br/>', $sname); // Name1<br/>Name2<br/>Name3
// etc.
```

**UPDATE**

```
$cout = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where parent_id='$update_id' ",$link);
echo '<select name="mySelectBox">';
while($cput = mysql_fetch_array($cout)){
    echo '<option value="Some Value">' . $cput['s_name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: This answer is really informative and thanks a lot . i gained some idea form your answer mate . Thanks

Comment: Agreed, not having to care about what exactly to do or watch out for when you can just add those items to an array and implode it afterwards is the best way to go. Leave silly little details to specialist functions that care, but don't litter your general code with these things.

Comment: @Marcus can you guide me how to implode to <option> </option> select box

Comment: @RajaGopal implode() wouldn't be the best-case for wrapping with <option></option>. What are you looking to accomplish? See update above.